# React-Router nginx proxy causing infinite redirection

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router

I have a react app that uses react-router with oidc and it is running inside an nginx container.It works fine. However, when it is proxied by another nginx container, react-router does not seem to be working. After a succesful oidc login, client app enters an infinite redirection.

At first i was having this issue , even when i run it without proxy. I've fixed that issue by adding try_files to nginx configuration.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

This is working fine. However, when this nginx container is proxied by another nginx container (lets say front nginx) , react-router seems to be disabled and routing is done by nginx,which resulted as redirection.Here is the configuration of the front nginx container

```
server {
        server_name panel-qa.test.com;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
        server_name panel-qa.test.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        .... SSL parameters removed for the sake of brevity
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
        include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://panel-qa.test.com;
        }
}
```

I haven't shared the react code here since i thought this issue is related to nginx configuration. I can share it upon request, since it is avaliable on github.

What could be the problem with front nginx app that disables react-router ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to my OIDC settings.Nothing to do with nginx or react-router.

Answer (score 0):

you are mentioning the same URL redirection in many places

you have to mention the home path in package.josn before you create to build you to set in package.json  home URL: domain.com

Error: there no error on Nginx config you have you use react history or hash router that keeps URL in react side

````
<HashRouter history={history}> 
   <Route path='/' component={IndexPage} exact={true} /> 
</HashRouter> ```
````